# Image Upload Strategy with Clusters And Amazon S3

Tags: php, image, amazon-s3

Trying to sort out a strategy to deal with uploaded images whose endpoint is Amazon S3.  The goal is, upon upload, that the image is immediately visible.  However, the current way of handling the situation is that the end-user uploads the image and then has to wait for it to be synced to Amazon S3 before being able to view it.  The other option was to simply temporarily display the item locally, but since we are using a cluster, that doesn't really work, because the image would only, upon upload, be available for view on the cluster server it was uploaded to.

One possible solution was to rsync the files to Amazon immediately upon upload, but for some reason, rsyncing from within the script wasn't seeming to work.  Is that not possible within a PHP script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all about how you display the images. Let's say an image has been uploaded and you stored the record about it in some shared storage (like DB), you saved the image id and the node specific url where the image was temporary placed. I hope you can access each individual node in your cluster.
When you display the image by its id, you go to the DB and pick that node specific  url, so it will be visible across the cluster. When the image has been uploaded to S3, you just swap that DB url for the new one on S3 and delete the image from that specific node.

Comment: Yes I can access via node and this is a great answer.  Thanks!